# Help with filter stability, ROC and output of a system

Tags: discrete-signals

I am trying to solve these two questions, but I am stuck with the filter stability and ROC. Hope somebody could help me with it.

[image: q1]
According to what I understand, the third option is correct. Fourth option is also incorrect as it only contains one pole and on zero. I think the first and second options are incorrect; the system is unstable and ROC doesn't include unit circle because the pole lies at z = -2 and the system is casual. Not sure though. I'd appreciate some help in this regard or if any of the other options are incorrect.

[image: q5]
For this question, the pole is outside the unit circle, so I thought the system must be unstable, but then I realize the output depends on future input (x[n+1]), which makes it non-casual, also number of zeros>poles. Since for a non-casual, the ROC moves inward, this system includes unit circle and is stable? But doubtful about the second part of the option regarding being dependent on input.

I wrote the following code to find y[n],

```
n = 100
w = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,n)
z = np.exp(1j * w)
H = z* (z - 0.5)/(z + 2)
t = np.arange(-n/2, n/2)   
x  = sp.unit_impulse(n) + 0.5 * sp.unit_impulse(n,1)
plt.plot(t,ifftshift(ifft( H * fft(x))))
```

Got the following result,
[image: here]

I don't think, 1st, 2nd and 5th options are correct, looking at figure. As I increased the value of n, the peak became narrower, so for the 4th option, I don't know if it is showing diverging oscillation. The only peak in this question is at zero.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Question 1 seems to work with the above logic. Stuck with no. 5 now.

Comment: Why don't you show the Z Transform of the 1st question and analyze the roots and poles?

Comment: @David Thanks.  I have solved the first question. Just needed help with the second one. I don't know why I was stuck with no. 1 for so long. It was pretty straight forward,

Answer (score 0):

For any filter with AR(1) component the coefficient must be smaller than in order to be stable. Otherwise any input is infinitely multiplied by a non decreasing factor.